# MonoTouch issues when binding ObjectiveC library

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make bindings for the Vfr PDF reader: https://github.com/vfr/Reader
This is an ObjectiveC application.

I followed the walkthrough from Xamarin there: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough/

Unfortunately I am still struggling on one issue. In my AppDelegate I instantiate a ReaderDemoController, which comes from the Vfr Reader library but, when running on the device (an iPhone5), it keeps saying:

```
Wrapper type 'Hager.VfrReaderCoreBinding.ReaderDemoController' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'ReaderDemoController'.
```

Which is strange since the Fat library contains i386, armv7, armv7s and arm64 libraries (done that using lipo). This is the LinkWith file content:

```cs
[assembly: LinkWith ("libVfrReaderCoreNative.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s, ForceLoad = true)]
```

In the ApiDefinition file this is the ReaderController interface:

```cs
[BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
public interface ReaderDemoController {
}
```

Nothing really "complicated". Any idea of what could be the cause?
This is the binding solution: [solution zipped](http://upload.hager.com/upload/66d08a5ccf1a18ec0d558dcdddd0b27e/Hager.VfrReaderCoreBinding.zip)

This is also not working in the simulator. I get :

```
Could not create an native instance of the type 'Hager.VfrReaderCoreBinding.ReaderDemoController': the native class hasn't been loaded.
```

It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

Comment: does it work in the simulator ? what's your LinkWith attribute ?

Comment: I edited and added the LinkWith content. It's also not working in the simulator. I get: "Could not create an native instance of the type 'Hager.VfrReaderCoreBinding.ReaderDemoController': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Objectice-C library wasn't built correctly, if you run `nm` on it you'll see it's almost empty:

```
$ nm libVfrReaderCoreNative.a

libVfrReaderCoreNative.a(VfrReaderCoreNative.o):
0000000000000000 s L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject
00000000000000d0 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_VfrReaderCoreNative
                 U _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject
00000000000000a8 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_VfrReaderCoreNative
                 U __objc_empty_cache
                 U __objc_empty_vtable
0000000000000060 s l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_VfrReaderCoreNative
0000000000000018 s l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_VfrReaderCoreNative
```

In particular nothing related to `ReaderDemoController`.

Comment: Many thanks Rolf it was an issue with the fat library